# Haxe externs for JS libraries

Tags: javascript, haxe

1. Does there exist any central place where all Haxe bindings for JS libraries are meant to be stored? Both if I want to find one, or submit one.
2. Is there some not outdated working tool to generate these bindings from TypeScript definitions?
3. Is there a binding for [nodejs ws library](https://github.com/websockets/ws)?

Answer (score 1):

1. http://lib.haxe.org also known as haxelib, the Haxe package manager. Other than that there are also libraries on Github, which you can install with `haxelib git libname https://github.com/bla/bla.git`
2. This kinda sounds like all libs are out of date. There is https://github.com/Simn/ts2hx as you might understand it is not a simple task to create such tool since TypeScript is a different (more dynamic) language and has a different type system which doesnt easily translate to haxe externs. In my experience this lib does 90% of the work. Also it isnt hard to create own externs, but I get you expect free direct-use libs. If tool/lib doesnt work please repot or contribute at the lib; Thats how opensource projects work.
3. I dont know

Hope this helps! Have a nice day!

Comment: 1. I know about haxelib. All or at least most haxe libraries are there. But that's not true for js bindings.

Answer (score 1):

1. Besides Haxelib, you can usually find a ton of stuff on GitHub (e.g. by searching for `jsrequire <foo> language:haxe` or other keywords).  There are also some privately curated extern collections like [clemos/js-kit](https://github.com/clemos/haxe-js-kit), [haxe-node-modules](https://github.com/proletariatgames/haxe-node-modules), [abedev/npm](https://github.com/abedev/npm)
2. [Simn/ts2hx](https://github.com/Simn/ts2hx) is the only one that comes to mind
3. I found [some externs](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=jsrequire+ws+language%3Ahaxe&type=Code), some of them inside other projects/libraries